# Can I use the word "very" wherever I want?

Tags: grammar

For Example:

> I like this **very** book.
>
> I written this **very** poem with ease.

Can I use the word "very" wherever I want?

Comment: Those sentences don't work. You could say "I've found the very book!" (meaning 'just the one I was looking for'.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on where you want to use the word.

**Very** can work either as an adverb, modifying another adverb or an adjective
or it can function as an adjective, modifying a noun.

In your examples, **very** functions as an adjective modifying **book** and **poem**, meaning **this particular book/poem**.

If you google **very part of speech**, you will find numerous examples and explanations, at sites such as these, of how the word can be used.

http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-very/
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/very